What are the legal rights of public school staff regarding item confiscation?
I'm looking for information specific to California, United States, but insights from other jurisdictions are also welcome.
From my research, I understand that school staff are permitted to confiscate items that disrupt the educational process (therefore violating others' right to education) or cause safety concerns.
However, what are the rights of teachers to confiscate items that do not directly cause a disruption or safety issue? Specifically:

What authority do teachers have to confiscate items that have the potential to disrupt the educational process but haven't yet done so? And who is someone to determines whether an item has the potential to disrupt the educational process? Because anyone could supposedly argue that anything could disrupt it.
Does the legal authority to confiscate items change when the student is 18 or older? For instance, do schools lose their "in loco parentis" authority once a student reaches adulthood?


Many states and school districts are debating whether to prohibit cellphones during class. If the teacher knows that there's ongoing discussion about this in their jurisdiction,  it would probably be inappropriate for them to make individual decisions to confiscate them, they should wait for the decision.

What authority do teachers have to confiscate items that have the potential to disrupt the educational process but haven't yet done so?
Teachers can confiscate items that only have the potential to disrupt the educational process. The teacher, individually, and the school, collectively, is in loco parentis which means that they have the broad authority of a parent with respect to the students in their care. Like a parent, a teacher can decide that a student shouldn't have something at a particular time.

And who is someone to determines whether an item has the potential to
disrupt the educational process?

The teacher in the first instance, subject to guidance and direction from the school administration to whom the teacher reports.

Does the legal authority to confiscate items change when the student
is 18 or older? For instance, do schools lose their "in loco parentis"
authority once a student reaches adulthood?

The school probably still have the authority to temporarily confiscate items, although possibly on a different legal theory.
First of all, in loco parentis is not inherently limited to people under age 18. Historically, colleges had in loco parentis authority over college students, but admittedly, this was mostly before the age of majority for most purposes was reduced from twenty-one years of age to eighteen years of age.
Secondly, if the school is no longer in loco parentis with respect to an eighteen year old or older student, then the student is attending, in theory at least, voluntarily, rather than pursuant to a mandatory attendance law or at the command of a parent. And, one of the implied condition that comes with adding an educational institution voluntarily is that you abide by that institution's rules. If you aren't willing to consent to temporary confiscation of your property by teachers, then the consequence may be expulsion from school for failing to submit to its rules.

Nearly half of high school seniors turn 18 during the school year. Do they suddenly switch from mandatory to voluntary attendance on their birthdays?

@Barmar In many states, attendance is only mandatory to ages 16 or 17, and none have a mandatory attendance age of more then 18. The fact that few students drop out on their birthdays when they are above the mandatory attendance age (as is common, for example, in New Zealand) is a function of social custom and the strong stigma associated with being a high school dropout in the U.S., rather than due to any legal obligation to continue their educations for the rest of their high school senior years. https://nces.ed.gov/programs/statereform/tab5_1.asp
